# Returning JSON from a JsonResult method in MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, jsonresult

I am trying to populate a ComboBox (Telerik RAD COmboBox) in a test ASP.NET MVC3 app.

I have defined the ComboBox on my ASPX page and in the controller I have defined the action call that returns a JsonResult.

The problem I am having is that the Web Service I am using already returns the resultset as a JSON string. How can I pass the response from the Webservice directly.

Here is the snippets of code:
ASPX page:

```
<% Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
                       .Name("cbRefTables")
                       .DataBinding(b => b
                           .Ajax()
                           .Select("GetCALMdata","Common")                    
                       )
                       .Render();
                %>
```

Controller: called CommomController

```
    public JsonResult GetCALMdata()
    {
        CALMwsP.wsCALMSoapClient wsC = new CALMwsP.wsCALMSoapClient("wsCALMSoap");
        string resultset = wsC.GetRefTables("P_1", "P_2", "P_3", "P_4");

        return ??; -- I want to return resultset which is already formatted. 
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the `resultset` string is already JSON (and not wrapped in any XML), then you'd want to return a `ContentResult` with exactly that string as the content:

```
public ContentResult GetCALMdata()
{
    CALMwsP.wsCALMSoapClient wsC = new CALMwsP.wsCALMSoapClient("wsCALMSoap");
    string resultset = wsC.GetRefTables("P_1", "P_2", "P_3", "P_4");

    return Content(resultset, "application/json");
}
```

You don't want to use `JsonResult` or the `Json()` helper in this case, because that's going to end up re-serializing your JSON.

Comment: The additional contentType parameter being set to `application/json` is what I needed. I was doing the Json serialization with Newtonsoft.Json rather than the built in one because I wanted some of serialization customisation it can do.

Answer (score 29):

If using ASP.NET MVC 2 or higher:

```
return Json(resultset, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: That is what I originally had, however I get the following error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Selected' is null or not an object

Comment: Well, that error isn't coming out of the controller. So your issue is with how you are handling the JSON.

Comment: most likely that error is from the combobox, it doesn't know what the default selected item should be

Comment: What is the using reference?

Answer (score 5):

if I correctly understood you should use the Json() method

```
return Json(resultset);
```

Comment: What is the using reference?

Answer (score 1):

The individual Json Method:

`return Json(resultset);`

It needs the **System.Web.Http** DLL and the namespace is *System.Web.Http.Results*.

[image]

---

Or Website wide put this line in the WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Comment: + for including DLL name and namespace.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC 5 and possibly below you can do something like this:

```
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "name", "Foobar" },
                { "url", "admin@foobar.com" }
            };

            var json = new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = dict
            };
```