# Unable to get json,only got xml

Tags: c#

Iam tried to display json array,but instead of json i got xml.How can i display json array

```
public HttpResponseMessage jsonvalues()
     {
         {
             var retList = new List<string>();

             RootObject ro = new RootObject();
             DataTable dtaltheat = GetAlltheatredet();
             foreach (DataRow drow in dtaltheat.Rows)
             {

                 string theatnme = drow["TheatreName"].ToString();
                 ro.name = theatnme;
                 JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                 var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);
                 if (jsonString != null)
                 {
                     retList.Add(jsonString);
                 }



                 // JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
             }
             // return retList;
             return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, retList);
         }
     }
```

iam using to display datatable contents and its woriking fine,but my only problem is that to unable to display json array...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this one: [Returning JSON from a JsonResult method in MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901411/returning-json-from-a-jsonresult-method-in-mvc-controller)

Believe this is where you are looking for:

> If using ASP.NET MVC 2 or higher:
>
> `return Json(resultset, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`